# How to get Silverstripe TableField to save records

Tags: php, silverstripe

I'm trying to use TableField to manage a list of related links to a page. I have the control working, except it isn't saving the id to the db (a hidden field), just the title and url

Is this the right way to be using it? think so. I've been using this: http://doc.silverstripe.org/sapphire/en/reference/tablefield as a guide

some code:

```
static $has_many = array ( 
    'Linketys' => 'Linkety',        
);

$myTableField = new TableField( 
 'MyTableField', // fieldName 
 'Linkety', // sourceType 
    array( 
    'Title'=>'Title', 
    'URL'=>'URL' 
    ), // fieldList 
    array( 
    'Title'=>'TextField', 
    'URL'=>'TextField' 
    ), // fieldTypes 
    null, // filterField (legacy) 
    "Linkety.PageID", 
    $this->ID 
    ); 
    // add some HiddenFields thats saved with each new row 
    $myTableField->setExtraData(array( 
        'PageID' => $this->ID ? $this->ID : '$RecordID' 
    )); 
    $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Content.Options", $myTableField);
```

Comment: i strongly recommend using the DataObjectManager module instead of built-in tablefield. the vast majority of silverstripe installations seems to make use of it as it has advanced features such as drag&drop reordering, integrated search and many more.
http://doc.silverstripe.org/old/modules:dataobjectmanager

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, the documentation seems to be a bit off.

This is how I use table fields, not using extraData

Linkety.php

```
class Linkety extends DataObject {
    public static $db = array(
        'Title'=>'Varchar',
        'URLSegment'=>'Varchar',
    );
    public static $has_one = array(
        'Page' => 'Page'
    );
}
```

In Page.php

```
$myTableField = new TableField(
    'Linkety',
    'Linkety',
    array('Title'=>'Link title', 'URLSegment'=>'URL'),
    array('Title'=>'TextField','URLSegment'=>'TextField'),
    'PageID',
    $this->ID,
    $editExisting=true
);
$fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Content.Options", $myTableField);
```